# How can I increase Crime in Tropico 4?

Tags: tropico-4

My current mission requires me to arrest 5 criminals. But I have practically no crime.

**How can I increase the crime rate?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, fire all cops and keep any police stations closed. Working police stations actively reduce the crime rate.

Second, make sure you have *way* more citizens than housing or jobs. Shacks increase crime rate, and only long-term unemployed people actually become criminals.

Third, if you have a Bar, issue the Mardi Gras Festival edict -- it increases both tourism and crime rate.

**EDIT**: I think there are a few more edicts that can affect the crime rate; I'll see about expanding this a bit when I get home tonight and sit down behind a computer that can play the game.

**EDIT 2** Okay, if you have Modern Times, also make sure you have the Police State edict deactivated (obvious reasons), and enable Prohibition. Note that the latter will seriously annoy non-Religious tropicans because you just closed every pub and nightclub by banning alcohol, so not getting revolts becomes a nontrivial exercise...

Comment: El Presidente is pleased with this answer.